# Attribute-Based Access control for nested attributes

Tags: access-control

Nested attributes were introduced for the first time in the paper with the title "SmartABAC: Enabling Constrained IoT Devices to Make Complex Policy-Based Access Control Decisions".
What is the difference between nested attributes, multiple attributes, and hierarchy attributes?
In this paper, the authors make 6 policy examples and claimed that their paper only supports P2, P3 and P5 policies. I think this is possible to support in other schemes like multi attribute ABAC or Hierarchical ABAC. Please explain more about it. Is nested atts only for simply expressiveness?

another question: Is the EAPs model in access control identityless? Isn't it equl to Access Control List (ACL)?

Answer (score 1):

Nested attributes are a form of hierarchy, but they are most useful for organization of **attribute names**. Examples:  `user.degree.university` and `user.job`.

Hierarchical attributes are used to represent semantic or sub-grouping rules in **attribute values**. Examples:

- considering that the attribute `user.job` accepts values `{BachelorStudent, PhDStudent, AssistantProfessor}`
- hierarchy: `BachelorStudent is a specialization of Student; PhDStudent is a specialization of Student`.

Regarding EAP, is not necessarily identityless. It is possible to make a rule `{user1, read, documentA}`, which is equivalent to an ACL. So you are right, ACLs are EAP -- and EAP is ACL with the possibility of being identityless.

(by the way, the paper claims to all support policies from p1 to p6: "As mentioned, all of the example policies in Table III are expressed using SmartABAC")